# PowerShellのカンマ演算子の挙動について

Tags: powershell

PowerShellのforeachステートメントでの挙動についてお聞きしたいです。
以下が通常のforeach文です。

```
$data = @('one','two','three')
foreach ($a in $data) {
    "$a"
}
one
two
three
```

配列の要素1つ1つが$aに代入されて出力されている認識です。
以下がお聞きしたいforeach文です。

```
$data = @('one', 'two', 'three')
foreach ($a in ,$data){
    "$a"
}
one two three
```

上記の文だと$aが配列になり、要素1つ1つが配列になった$aに代入されて出力されるイメージであってますでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

正しいです。`.GetType()`で型を調べることで確認できます。

```
PS> $data.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


PS> $data[0].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

と`$data`は`Object[]`であり、その先頭要素`$data[0]`は`String`です。

`$data2 = ,$data`としたうえで

```
PS> $data2 = ,$data
PS> $data2.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


PS> $data2[0].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


PS> $data2[0][0].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

と`$data2`は`Object[]`ですが、その先頭要素`$data2[0]`は`Object[]`となります。更に先頭要素`$data2[0][0]`が`String`となります。